# How to add custom setting/attribute to existing View?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I used to work with web pages frontend and after moving to Xamarin.Forms and its XAML, I tend to miss some specific features.

I HTML, you can add some attributes to object, just to store some additional information about it:

```
<div x-show-success-message="Completed!" class="someObjectType"></div>
```

Then, you can get data from this x-some-custom-data whenever you want.

I'm looking for something similar in XAML. The only way I is creating completly new object (in Xamarin it's called View):

```
public class ButtonWithStorage : Button
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty StringDataProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
      propertyName: "StringData",
      returnType: typeof(string),
      declaringType: typeof(ButtonWithStorage),
      defaultValue: default(string));


    /// <summary>
    /// You can put here some properties
    /// </summary>
    public string StringData
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(StringDataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StringDataProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

And then using it in XAML like:

```
<x:ButtonWithStorage StringData="Some property" />
```

It admittedly works, but it's not "handy". It requires configuring new object each time I want add some custom property and doesn't work for existing XAML object like `<StackLayout>`

Are there some better ways to do that?

PS: It would be also nice to know, if it is something in XAML like "class" attribute in HTML, where you can generally name some specific type of objects.

Comment: i really cannot follow you. What do you mean with "doesn't work for existing XAML object like <StackLayout>". You have already answered your question by the Button code example. If you want to extent a stacklayout just derive from it and extended as you did with the button. Then use it in XAML. It is the best way because it is an OOP way.

Comment: In XAML you have the `StyleId` which may do what you mean by the class attribute. Furthermore, the functionality you want isn't available. HTML is much more flexible and does not have strong typing etc. So you can do stuff like that. There isn't any support for dynamic types like that in XAML and honestly I don't think you should want it.